# Sufficiently large prime numbers $6z + 1$ are not all of the form $36xy - 6x + 6y + 1$ for $x,y \neq 0$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The polynomial $36xy - 6x + 6y + 1$ seems to be irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}$ or even $\Bbb{Z}[i]$.  I don't know if that matters, but, I don't think all large enough primes of the form $6z + 1$ can "follow the pattern": $36xy - 6x + 6y + 1,$ for $x,y \neq 0, \ x,y \in \Bbb{Z}$.

So I have the tendency that the prime numbers generally never follow some simple pattern on the side of the conjecture as evidence.

Is there some elementary argument that can prove this?

Comment: Maybe $$36xy-6x+6y+1=(6x+1)(6y-1)+2$$ helps

Comment: Try with: $x=(6\cdot y+1)\cdot c$ or $y=(6\cdot x-1)\cdot d$

Comment: If $(p,p+2)$ is a twin-prime with $p>3$ , then $p+2$ is a prime of the form $6z+1$ that cannot be of this form. Not sure , whether those primes are the only ones with this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is a prime of the form $6n+1$ such that $6n-1$ is not prime , then $p$ can be written in the form $$p=36xy-6x+6y+1$$

Proof : The prime factors of $6n-1$ have all the form $6m-1$ or $6m+1$ since $2$ and $3$ are not prime factors. If all prime factors were of the form $6m+1$ , the number would have the form $6n+1$ which is not the case. Therefore $6n-1$ has a prime factor of the form $6y-1$ , the cofactor must then have the form $6x+1$ , hence we have
$$6n-1=(6x+1)(6y-1)=36xy-6x+6y-1$$ hence $$6n+1=36xy-6x+6y+1$$

On the other hand , a prime $p$ of the form $6n+1$ cannot be of this form if $6n-1$ is prime as well because $6x+1$ and $6y-1$ have absolute value greater than $1$ hence the product cannot be a prime.

So, the desired representation for a prime $p=6n+1$ exists iff $p-2$ is composite. Since we probably have infinite many twin primes , there should be infinite many primes of the form $6n+1$ not having the desired representation.